# VS 2017 and Resharper Colors

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

After importing a new theme and spending a lot of time tweaking things to my liking, I'm very happy with how the text editor displays...except for one small component.

The tips that pop up showing variable values while debugging are nearly unreadable, with very poor contrast (background is white with pastel text). I cannot recall if these are from CodeLens or Resharper, but neither can I find the setting to update these.

[Here's a screenshot of the debug tips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oqat.jpg)

Can anyone tell me what these windows/tips are officially called, and if they're from VS or Resharper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is comming from R#, there are a couple of configurations for it
Under `Environment > Products & Features > Debugger integration` you can uncheck to not show them at all.
Under `Tools > Debugger` you have also several options regarding this, my guess is that you are using the `Text Editor Font`, try to use `Visual Studio IntelliSense Font`
EDIT
Regarding the theme, you can change all the colors of R# under `VS Options> Fonts and Colors` and I think the one you are looking for is the `ReSharper Debugger DataTip`

Comment: Thanks for the info Nekeniehl, it was the font setting that was throwing me off, switching from intellisense font to editor font enabled my color customizations to take effect.

Comment: You're welcome, if it was helpful and it fix your problem, you can mark the answer so anybody else can know that is correct and follow the same steps.